# Problem with jQuery load() and Facebook XFBML

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, jquery-ui, xfbml

**The situation**

I open a layer (jQueryUI) like this.

```
$("#dialog").load('userinfo.html #layer').dialog('open');
```

*userinfo.html* displays the photo and the name of a facebook user.

```
  <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <...some code...>
    <div id="layer">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {   
        FB.init("2342342423424", "http://www.mysite.com/xd_receiver.htm");  
        });
      </script>  
      <fb:profile-pic uid="200000999530485" size="square" linked="true"></fb:profile-pic> <fb:name uid="200000999530485"></fb:name>
     </div>
   <...some code...>
</html>
```

**The problem:**

The layer opens but the **fbml tags are not rendered!** 
Please help. I think load() doenst load the js-part.

(If i open the userinfo.html in the browser everything works finde)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$("#dialog").load('userinfo.html #layer', function() {
  FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('dialog'));
});
$("#dialog").dialog('open');
```

Notice that it's being called in the load callback in order to ensure the Ajax request has completed and the data has been loaded before the XFBML parsing has been triggered.

Comment: Good point, should parse fbml on load callback. That's what I got wrong.

Comment: @serg555 - yep, exactly. Added a note to highlight that fact.

Answer (score 1):

As for as I know, facebook needs this namespace:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Make sure that you are specifying that or try giving the id to it instead of the later div:

```
<html id="layer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Answer (score 1):

FBML tags are not rendered if they are not present on the page from the beginning (i.e. you load fbml tags through ajax into some div). In order to render them you would need to do some extra work.

First of all, all js stuff should be moved to your main window (fb js include, fb init). userinfo.html should contain only fbml and html. Auto FBML parsing should be disabled in `FB.init({xfbml  : false})` (I don't remember, it might work with auto parsing on but I think I had to turn it off).

You need to mark a place where your future fbml will be loaded dynamically with `fb:serverFbml` tag:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <fb:serverFbml id="dialog-fbml"></fb:serverFbml>
</div>
```

Your fbml loading script now would look like:

```
$("#dialog-fbml").load('userinfo.html #layer'); //load fbml
FB.XFBML.parse($("#dialog")[0]); //parse it
$("#dialog").dialog('open'); //show
```

Comment: Thanks, but this opens userinfo.html in the current tab:
FB.XFBML.parse($("#dialog"));

Comment: @fabian: as I understand `#dialog` is just a div on your page which you want to turn into popup with dynamically loaded fbml? Just make it hidden until it is displayed.

Comment: @fabia: see daaku'a answer, need to put parsing into load's callback.

Answer (score 0):

If i parse the XFBML with some delay, everything works fine. Isnt there a callback method for dialog('open'), is there?

```
      $("#dialog").load('userinfo.html #layer');
      $("#dialog").dialog('open');        
      setTimeout(function() {FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('#dialog'));} ,4000);
```